# move words into a specific area

Tags: html, css

Problem- How to move the line from this example below "Hi I'm a developer that loves clean & elegant code"

From this position

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgrC9.png

into this position

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yEMO.png

---

HTML of the section (the order of anything isn't aloud to be changed EX.cant just move "Hi, i'm a developer..." right above the "A little bit about me" line)

```
<body>
   <header>
     <div class="full-width">
       <div class="half-width">
         <h1>Jubilee Austin</h1>
       </div>
       <div class="half-width">
         <h2><span>Hi,</span> i'm a developer that loves clean &amp; elegant code.
         </h2>
         <nav>
           <ul>
             <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
             <li><a href="#work">Work</a></li>
             <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
             </ul>
         </nav>
       </div>
     </div>
   </header>
   <main>
     <section id="about">
       <div class="full-width">
         <h2>A little bit about me</h2>
         <div class="half-width">
           <p> i've made my home base in Providence, Rhode Island with my small growing family. My journey into tech started with a degree in journalism.As I started sharing my writing online, I was fascinated with how easily I could get my voice out there. I was hooked and wanted to learn how to build my own site to fit my own specific needs.</p>
         </div>
           <div class="half-width">
             <p>That curiosity then opened a door that could never be shut. When I learned how to build my first website, I realized I found something that gave me the freedom &amp; versatility I was looking for in my work. Now I've made a full switch to front-end development, where I can use my organization skills and eye for detail to write clean, elegant code.</p>
           </div>
           </div>
     </section>
```

---

Entire CSS

```
/****Base syles***/
body {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}
#about, #work, #contact {
  height: 600px;
  border: solid red;
}
/***Grid***/
.full-width{
  width:1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.half-width{
  width:600px;
  float:left;
}
.third-width{
  width:400px:
  float:left;
}
/***About specific***/
#about .full-width{
  padding:80px 0;
}
#about h2{
  font-family: 'Lora', serif;
  font-size:36px;
  color:#262a2b;
}

#about p{
  font-size:21px;
  color:#7f7f7f;
  line-height:42px;
  padding-right:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

The example below has been updated to a pure CSS solution to your use case in regard to keeping the document structure the same. Here is the relevant tidbit:

```
@media (max-width: 1234px) {
  .hi {
    left: 10px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1235px) {
  .hi {
    left: calc(50% - 600px);
  }
}

.hi {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
}
```

**Notes:**

- `position: absolute` is used to move the element out of the normal document flow to where it is needed.
- `@media` queries are used to match your `width` settings.
- the odd numbers `1234px/1235px` are calculated from when you `width` exceeds that specified in your `.full-width` class. It combines the `1200px` of your specified full width with `20px` from the browser scroll bar and `14px/15px` from the default margin applied to the document body.

See and run the code below to see that it satisfies your use case:

```css
/****Base syles***/
body {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}
#about, #work, #contact {
  height: 600px;
  border: solid red;
}
/***Grid***/
.full-width{
  width:1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.half-width{
  width:600px;
  float:left;
}
.third-width{
  width:400px;
  float:left;
}

@media (max-width: 1234px) {
  .hi {
    left: 10px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1235px) {
  .hi {
    left: calc(50% - 600px);
  }
}

.hi {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
}

/***About specific***/
#about .full-width{
  padding:80px 0;
}
#about h2{
  font-family: 'Lora', serif;
  font-size:36px;
  color:#262a2b;
}

#about p{
  font-size:21px;
  color:#7f7f7f;
  line-height:42px;
  padding-right:50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
   <header>
     <div class="full-width">
       <div class="half-width">
         <h1>Jubilee Austin</h1>
       </div>
       <div class="half-width">
         <h2 class='hi'><span>Hi,</span> i'm a developer that loves clean &amp; elegant code.</h2>
         <nav>
           <ul>
             <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
             <li><a href="#work">Work</a></li>
             <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
             </ul>
         </nav>
       </div>
     </div>
   </header>
   <main>
     <section id="about">
       <div class="full-width">
         
         
         <h2>A little bit about me</h2>
         <div class="half-width">
           <p> i've made my home base in Providence, Rhode Island with my small growing family. My journey into tech started with a degree in journalism.As I started sharing my writing online, I was fascinated with how easily I could get my voice out there. I was hooked and wanted to learn how to build my own site to fit my own specific needs.</p>
         </div>
           <div class="half-width">
             <p>That curiosity then opened a door that could never be shut. When I learned how to build my first website, I realized I found something that gave me the freedom &amp; versatility I was looking for in my work. Now I've made a full switch to front-end development, where I can use my organization skills and eye for detail to write clean, elegant code.</p>
           </div>
           </div>
     </section>
```

*Old solution:* You can just move the `<h2><span>Hi,</span> i'm a developer that loves clean &amp; elegant code.</h2>` line to right before the `<h2>A little bit about me</h2>` segment.

Comment: This Isn't a bad answer, its correct, but its not correct in my situation, side information for my question the HTML needed to be exact and cant just be moved around like that, I'm thinking its probably more to do with the CSS

Comment: No problem. But I and others can only work off of what information you provide us with. Can you please elaborate in detail what your requirements are in your question so that others can understand fully what you are asking for?

Comment: I have updated the answer to your use case. Pure CSS!